# how to convert dataframe with columns(x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4) in a given csv file into a series without adding data manually

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

how to convert dataframe with columns(x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4) in a given csv file into a series(s1,s2,s3,s4)  without adding data manually. series has to be like (x,y) format.And again convert that series into dataframe to obtain descriptive statics and Plot a scatterplot in Python using the correct method in the Matplotlib library for each dataset[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLV02.png)

[The way I try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itk9Y.png)

Comment: It would be helpful for you to read the announcement and then ask your questions. (1.[mre], 2.[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 3.[why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)) Your questions are not well-structured: the input is not provided as text, the desired output is not clear, and you are trying to ask too many questions at once.