# convert dataframe into series

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Construct in Python four Series (s1,s2,s3,s4) to store the four data sets (I, II, III, IV), and then convert the Series into data frames (df1, df2, df3, df4), Each dataset consists of eleven (x,y)points;[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GPIZ.png)

[Things I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2igN1.png)

Comment: Please don't use images of code/data. A [mre] (as **text**) is required.

Comment: Also you already asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78171473/)